# How can I get the number of threads running in a process from /proc/[pid]/stat in Linux?

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, c, proc

I have the pid of the process. I would like to know the current number of thread running in the process. I know I can read /proc/pid/stat for this information, but I'm not sure how to specifically get the number of threads from stat. Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/268680/how-can-i-monitor-the-active-thread-count-of-a-process-jvm-on-linux

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The number of entries in `/proc/pid/task` is the number of threads in the process. Also, `/proc/pid/status` has a `Threads` line. In `/proc/pid/stat`, it's the 20th field.

Comment: Ah that a lot I would try this but I just realized my method to get the process id is incorrect. I'm running user space code that read and writes to a proc file. I use a module to do the read and writes to a proc file. Within the module code, can I get the process id of the process that tries to write to a proc file? Thanks for any help!

Comment: If you want to get your own information, just use `/proc/self`, it's a shortcut for getting your own PID and composing a path containing it. Of course, you can also call `getpid` to get your own PID.

Comment: I believe getpid() from a user-space library and does not work in kernel space. Is this true? Or is there a kernel version? Otherwise I will try the /proc/self thanks!

Comment: If you want to do it from kernel code, look at how `proc` does it and copy that. You need a `task_struct` and you need to atomically read its `signal->count` member. To access the current task, use `current`.